# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null while targeting id deep inside body id

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to target an id deep inside the body with the id of #single-couple bla bla bla. In the process, I am getting an error of "Cannot read property of 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null. It has been a while since I have worked with javascript so I am not sure where my error is.
My Javascript code is as follows:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){   
let couplesTextCode = document.getElementById('#single-couple-special-playa-del-carmen-chichen-itza #booking-request');
let couplesText = "<span class=`if-small` style=`font-size: 12px; line-height: 90%;color: #5e6d77;`> (per couple)</span><br><span class=`if-small` style=`font-size: 16px;color: #5e6d77; line-height: 90%;`>Special Offer!</span><br><span style=`font-size: 14px; color:#5e6d77 ;line-height: .75;`>Call us for this special offer: <strong>MyPhoneNumber</strong><br>or Email us at <strong><a href=`mailto:info@evolution35.com`>email@myemail.com</a></strong><br>Receive Confirmation within 2 hours</span>";
couplesTextCode.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", couplesText);
});
</script>
```

And the html is as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="widgets">
    <div class="fixed-on-mobile" id="booking-request" data-screen="992px">  
      <div class="form-book-wrapper relative">
        <div class="loader-wrapper">
          <div class="st-loader"></div>
            <div class="form-head">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="label"></span>
                <span class="value">
                <span class="text-lg lh1em item "> $2,580.00</span><span class="if-small" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 90%;"> (per person)</span><br><span class="if-small" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 90%;">Price Based On double Occupancy</span> </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill-st" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a id="nav-book-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-book" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Book</a></li>
                <li><a id="nav-inquirement-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-inquirement" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Inquiry</a></li>
              </ul>
           </nav>
<div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="nav-book" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-book-tab">
    <form id="form-booking-inpage" method="post" action="#booking-request" class="tour-booking-form">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="tours_add_to_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="10143">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_tour" value="specific_date">
      <div class="form-group form-date-field form-date-search clearfix " data-format="MM/DD/YYYY" data-availability-date="06/22/2021">
        <div class="date-wrapper clearfix">
          <div class="check-in-wrapper">
            <label>Date</label>
            <div class="render check-in-render">06/22/2021</div>
              <span class="sts-tour-checkout-label hidden"><span> - </span><div class="render check-out-render">06/22/2021</div></span>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow"></i>
        </div>
          <input type="text" class="check-in-input" value="06/22/2021" name="check_in">
          <input type="hidden" class="check-out-input" value="06/22/2021" name="check_out">
          <input type="text" class="check-in-out-input" value="22/06/2021 12:00 am-22/06/2021 12:00 am" name="check_in_out" data-action="st_get_availability_tour_frontend" data-tour-id="10143" data-posttype="st_tours">
       </div>
      <div class="form-group form-more-extra st-form-starttime" style="display: none">
        <input type="hidden" data-starttime="" data-checkin="06/22/2021" data-checkout="06/22/2021" data-tourid="10143" id="starttime_hidden_load_form" data-posttype="st_tours">
      <div class="" id="starttime_box">
        <label>Start time</label>
        <select class="form-control st_tour_starttime" name="starttime_tour" id="starttime_tour"></select>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-guest-search clearfix ">
    <div class="guest-wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="check-in-wrapper">
        <label>Adults</label>
        <div class="render">Age 12 or 12+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="guest-wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="check-in-wrapper">
    <label>Room</label>
    <div class="render">Max 2 infants per room. 3 Adults &amp; 1 children (under 12) Or 2 Adults &amp; 2 children (under 12) </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
  </div>
```

For the sake of brevity, I removed the rest of the html code so there will be missing tags and divs. I left the most relevant code so as to not add to much unnecessary code.

The bottom line is that I am not sure how to target such deeply nested ids. Also, I cannot directly change the code as it is a wordpress template (and I don't have access to the code and it could change when the template updates) and I only want to employ js on this page only and not the other pages that have similar code.

I appreciate the help on this. I have searched for an answer in StackOverflow and all the adjacentHTML solutions did not help. Thank you.

Comment: Typo: You confused getElementById and querySelector

Comment: "all the adjacentHTML solutions did not help" — Your problem is that getElementById is returning null, which is nothing to do with adjacentHTML

Comment: Absolutely right. Thank you. I changed it to querySelector and it worked like a charm. Thank you. If you can post it as an aswer, I will mark it as correct.